# exception unhandled in c# data validation drop down list

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am trying to add a dropdown list to the cell in the 11th column. I used a code snippet from stackoverflow, but an exception is thrown

```
((Excel.Range)mysheet.Cells[row_counter, 10]).Value2 = loginname; //works
var list = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
list.Add("okay");
list.Add("unknown");
list.Add("delete");
list.Add("else (Comment)");
var flatList = string.Join(",", list.ToArray());
var cell = (Excel.Range)mysheet.Cells[row_counter, 11];
cell.Validation.Delete();
cell.Validation.Add(
     Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList, 
     Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation, 
     Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, 
     flatList , Type.Missing
);
cell.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
cell.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
cell.Locked = false; // the whole sheet is protected, mysheet.Protect(UserInterfaceOnly: true);
```

The unhandled exception is`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'`. Everything else works fine in the code. I read that the order of the commands matter but I think I did this correctly. Can somebody help me, where is the mistake.

Comment: Hi @Suslik - Can you give us some more details?  How many total rows are in this spreadsheet?  Are you using a `.xls` or `.xlsx` file?  Which specific line gives you the exception?

Comment: Hello gravity. I work with `.xls` and the exception is thrown in the `cell.Validation.Add(...)`. If I fill the cell just with a normal string the code works fine. There are 14 rows in the sheet, it is just a small test file.

Comment: I got the solution. The problem was that I cannot protect the sheet and use this command. If I work with an unprotected sheet it works.